# how rewrite a nested list changing the complex values to their Norm

Tags: list-manipulation

have this nested list

```
tabcompx ={{ 
{1, 1.24949 - 0.168098 I}, {2, 1.2877 - 0.186127 I},      
{3, 1.25285 - 0.23586 I}, {4, 1.19284 - 0.348902 I},  
{5, 1.15256 - 0.530763 I}, {6, 1.17072 - 0.76506 I}, 
{7, 1.27198 - 1.01933 I}, {8, 1.46257 - 1.25409 I}, 
{9, 1.73079 - 1.43159 I}, {10, 2.05021 - 1.52227 I}}}
```

as you can see the first value is real and the second one is a complex number,  the real list is almost 1000 couple of values, but I need convert each complex value to their Norm.

According to Wolfram Documentation Center, to do this I need to use something like this

```
tabcompx[[All, 2]] = Norm[{#}]; tabcompx
```

it suppouse the first value not change, but se second values (the complex number) will be change to their norm. But not work at all.

Thanks for any helpfull Hint

Comment: `tabcompx[[1, All, 2]] = Norm /@ tabcompx[[1, All, 2]];
tabcompx`?

Comment: .. or `tabcompx /. x_Complex :> Norm[x]` if only the second entry is `Complex` in each pair.

Answer (score 2):

```
tabcompx[[1, All, 2]] = Norm /@ tabcompx[[1, All, 2]]; 
tabcompx
```

> {{{1, 1.26075}, {2, 1.30108}, {3, 1.27486}, {4, 1.24282}, {5, 
>          1.2689}, {6, 1.39854}, {7, 1.63002}, {8, 1.92662}, {9, 
>          2.24613}, {10, 2.55356}}}

If complex values appear only in the second part of pairs, you can also use

```
tabcompx /. x_Complex :> Norm[x]
```

to get the same result.